# Display modals by passing it path dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am having the following code for the modal in which i have defined the path of a single modal. I took this code from ui-bootstarp, i need to remove unwanted lines also and to resize the modal dynamically

```
<div ng-controller="ModalCtrl" class="">
   <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

here is the html code, the following is script

```
var ModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
$scope.open = function () {
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'views/modals/modal_startup_add.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
}; 
};


var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };



$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

i need to remove the unwanted lines from the script

Comment: Why do you think there are unwanted lines of code. Actually there is no unwanted code here.

Comment: "items" i dont want to use it , i am just started to learn angular how can i replace the "$scope.item" in "resolve"

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think there are unwanted lines of code. Actually there is no unwanted code here.

See the plnkr at http://plnkr.co/edit/SuCUTKGy93MPXXsupxJJ?p=preview

URL of the modal has been passed to the open function.

> To resize the modal

Refer : http://plnkr.co/edit/QnekINr3L82LKr2R7POB?p=info

Comment: i need modal with my custom element in order to that want to remove "items"